# Best practices for reading large json files?

Tags: php, json, node.js, mongodb, couchdb

I have a few gigs of data stored as json, is it best to load them into mongodb or couchdb (probably on a remote host like Mongolab), a flat-file json db like http://fatfreeframework.com/jig, parse the files directly on the server using PHP (or Node, etc) or some other method?  The files are huge, it wouldn't be good to have to load them into memory but I'm open to everything.

Comment: I think the answer depends on what you are planning on doing with the data after you have it in a new format.

Comment: I'm going to grab a few values and send them to the client via ajax.

Comment: Definitely put them into a database.  Parse several GB for one request, that is crazy talk.

Comment: Hmm, how big is "large" ?

Comment: Open the large file as stream and use [JSONStream](https://npmjs.org/package/JSONStream) to parse the large file.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to:

1. Store a lot of data in JSON format
2. Query for a specific JSON document
3. Return a small portion of the matching document

I can't speak for CouchDB, but this is pretty easy in MongoDB:

1. load your JSON documents into MongoDB using [`mongoimport`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#bin.mongoimport).
2. Index the fields you'll be querying on using [`ensureIndex()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/)
3. Use the [`find()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) command to query for the desired document (`criteria` parameter) and return the target key subset (`projection` parameter)

The main limitation here is the size of your "huge" JSON documents. MongoDB limits each document to 16MB, so if they're larger than that you'll need to strip out some data or do some fancy tricks to make it work. If they do fit under that limit, then MongoDB should be a pretty good way to meet your requirement.